# How to display js2-mode warnings

Tags: javascript, js2-mode

I am running Emacs 26.1 on Ubuntu 16.4. I am writing Javascript using js2-mode. When the linter underlines a line of code, I want to know what error or warning it has detected. For example, in this code:

```
function() { 
   return;
   return true;
}
```

js2-mode will underline the line

```
return true;
```

Because it cannot be reached after the first return statement, thus generating a warning. However, I cannot find anywhere where js2-mode actually shows me any text that explains why it has underlined that line. I gather that this should be possible, but the mode line and the mini buffer are both clear. Do I need to enable something or customize a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, I don't use `js2-mode`, but doing `M-x js2-display-error-list RET` will open a buffer with all the errors in it. Do `C-h f js2-display-error-list RET` to get more info.

Comment: Do you know if this is for a particular version of js2-mode? I don't seem to have that function. The closest autocomplete is js2-mode-display-warnings-and-errors.

Comment: I looked at the current version posted on github.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working.